# ServerBag can not be transformed into a string when modifying a resource

Tags: php, laravel

I do not really understand why this is happening but it tells me that ServerBag could not be converted to characters, I do not really understand what the ServerBag is and why this error occurs.

Error:

[image]

…\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Str.php354

[image]

Relevant code (function update):

```
   $request->validate([
         'username' => 'required|string|max:50',
         'password' => 'required|string|max:50',
         'port' => 'max:5',
         'server' => 'string|nullable|max:50',
         'hostname' => 'string|nullable|max:100',
         'ipvmware' => 'string|nullable|ipv4',
         'obs' => 'string|nullable|max:500',
    ]);

    $host = Host::find($id);
    $host->username = $request->username;
    $host->password = $request->password;

    if($request->input('port')){
        $host->port = $request->port;
    }
    if($request->input('server')){
        $host->server = $request->server;
    }
    if($request->input('hostname')){
        $host->hostname = $request->hostname;
    }
    if($request->input('ipvmware')){
        $host->ipvmware = $request->ipvmware;
    }
    if($request->input('obs')){
        $host->obs = $request->obs;
    }

    $host->estado = 1;
    $host->save();
```

The code works if I delete the following lines.

```
   $request->validate([
        'username' => 'required|string|max:50',
        'password' => 'required|string|max:50',
        'port' => 'max:5',
        'server' => 'string|nullable|max:50',
        'hostname' => 'string|nullable|max:100',
        'ipvmware' => 'string|nullable|ipv4',
        'obs' => 'string|nullable|max:500',
    ]);

    $host = Host::find($id);
    $host->username = $request->username;
    $host->password = $request->password;


    $host->estado = 1;
    $host->save();
```

dd($request->all()):

[image]

Comment: one of your `$request` fields contains an array of headers, see: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.0/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ServerBag.php

Comment: update my question I think this gives an approach where the problem could be.

Comment: so after removing the ifs statements the error disappear?

Comment: yes, but I do not understand why, will there be another way to see if the fields are empty? maybe it's by using the function $ request-> input ()

Comment: try: `dd($request->all())`

Comment: updated the post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192007/discussion-between-victor-nunez-and-loic-lopez).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your "if" conditions.

#### Solution

```
if ($request->input('port')) // <----
{
    $host->port = $request->port;
}
```

Try this instead:

```
if ($request->has('port')) // <----
{
    $host->port = $request->port;
}
```

---

## Update

You should check first if your desired input exists in the request. From the docs:

> #### Determining If An Input Value Is Present
>
> You should use the has method to determine if a value is present on
>   the request. The has method returns true if the value is present on
>   the request:
>
> ```
> if ($request->has('name')) {
>     //
> }
> ```

Then you should get the input.

Now, related to the methods:

#### [$request->has()](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithInput.html#method_has)

When doing `$request->has(...)` you are checking if the request contains a given input item key (or keys). This is what the method does:

```
# trait InteractsWithInput.php

/**
 * Determine if the request contains a given input item key.
 *
 * @param  string|array  $key
 * @return bool
 */
public function has($key)
{
    $keys = is_array($key) ? $key : func_get_args();

    $input = $this->all();

    foreach ($keys as $value) {
        if (! Arr::has($input, $value)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

As you can see, it just returns a boolean.

#### [$request->input(...)](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithInput.html#method_input)

When doing `$request->input(...)` you are trying to get an input from the request:

```
# trait InteractsWithInput.php

/**
 * Retrieve an input item from the request.
 *
 * @param  string|null  $key
 * @param  string|array|null  $default
 * @return string|array|null
 */
public function input($key = null, $default = null)
{
    return data_get(
        $this->getInputSource()->all() + $this->query->all(), $key, $default
    );
}
```

The thing with this method is that is a little more powerful, cause it can take nested data using dot notation (as opposed to the `$request->get()` one). Check [this article](https://laraveldaily.com/differences-request-get-vs-request-input-vs-helper-vs-get_data/) for more details.

This will return a `string`, `array` or `null`.

Now this is where the error is located (as you can check if in your error trace). It seems that this method is trying to treat a given object as an string in order to resolve the if statement (I don't really know because don't have access yo tour full error detail).

So first, check if the request **has** the specific attribute and then **retrieve the input** to do what you need.

Comment: I understand, do you know what is the difference between each of the functions?